# VC++ 11 - std::condition_variable_any not compatible with standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, condition-variable

Recently, I ran into strange compilation issues on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (equipped with Visual C++ 11).

I ported large code base, developed mostly on Linux with extensive C++ 11 usage in mind. Despite few minor changes, everything was working fine. Except one thing: I got strange error about result type of [std::condition_variable::wait_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any/wait_for). Its content is irrelevant here, because I checked this and...

Reference page (linked above) says:

```
template< class Lock, class Rep, class Period >
std::cv_status wait_for(Lock&, const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>&)
```

And:

```
template< class Lock, class Rep, class Period, class Predicate >
bool wait_for(Lock&, const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>&, Predicate)
```

I have used `std::cv_status` in some places, so I can say, I rely on its presence. However, on **MSVC11**,  `<conditional_variable>` contains:

```
template<class _Lock, class _Rep, class _Period>
bool wait_for(_Lock& _Lck, const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& _Rel_time)
```

And:

```
template<class _Lock, class _Rep, class _Period, class _Predicate>
bool wait_for(_Lock& _Lck, const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& _Rel_time, _Predicate _Pred)
```

Note the different result type in first case. I was like:

> Errr... what?

I checked this immediately back on Linux (`g++ 4.8`) and these two methods were indeed defined properly.

What's going on here? MS has released implementation not compatible with standard?

Curious thing is, that I further investigated `<condition_variable>` and I have found this:

```
namespace cv_status {   // names for wait returns
    enum cv_status {
        timeout,
        no_timeout
    };
} // namespace cv_status
```

But it is:

- unused
- invalid **<sup>(*)</sup>**

Is this some well-known bug? Or perhaps standard allows implementations to do this?

---

**<sup>(*)</sup>** Standard defines [`enum class cv_status`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/cv_status), not `enum class cv_status::cv_status`.

---

One more thing: `wait_for` calls internally `wait_until`, which looks like this:

```
bool _Res;
_Mtx_lock(&_Mtx);
_Xtrnl.unlock();
_Res = _Cnd_timedwaitX(&_Cnd, &_Mtx, _Abs_time) != _Thrd_timedout;
_Mtx_unlock(&_Mtx);
_Xtrnl.lock();
return (_Res);
```

So, interpretation of the result is:

- `true` -> `std::cv_status::no_timeout`
- `false` -> `std::cv_status::timeout`

If there was requirement, that `no_timeout` must be defined as `1` and `timeout` as `0` it would be fine, but I don't see anything like this. Actually, on Linux, there was:

```
enum class cv_status { no_timeout, timeout };
```

So these enumerators would be converted to bool in different way than on Windows.

Comment: If you want to be taken seriously, quit writing Microsoft with a dollar sign. Act like an adult, even if it's only on this site.

Comment: I have a great respect for this company. I use a lot of their products and can't imagine working without them. I also understand costs, priorities, deadlines etc. I also work as a developer as well, so I get, that there are important things and more important things. But, hey - I act as a mature and trying to rely on mature software, that I pay for (quite serious money, by the way). I'm simply disappointed (but in case of **MS**, I'm starting to getting use to it).

Comment: There are plenty of shortcomings and bugs in Microsoft's C++11 compliance still. It doesn't help that you're not using their latest compiler, of course, so yeah, it seems likely that there are issues with their implementation. Regarding the definition of `cv_result`, I'd imagine that it's a workaround because this compiler doesn't support `class enum`. I haven't checked though, just a guess.

Comment: @jalf It **does** support it. I use scoped enums very intensively without any problems.

Comment: Already fixed in VC12 (2013).

Comment: I have VS 2013 EE update 4 installed and see that's fixed: `template<class _Lock, class _Rep, class _Period> _Cv_status wait_for(_Lock& _Lck, const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& _Rel_time)`

Comment: Also, note that VC11 (2012)'s standard library were still using "fake scoped enums" (unscoped enums wrapped in a namespace) ["due to a long story involving a compiler bug with /clr"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the version number of Visual C++ 11.0, Visual Studio 2012 does not support C++11 and does not claim to support it. Not even the next version (Visual Studio 2013) does: there is a CTP to add significant C++11 features, but even then, the support is incomplete. [Visual Studio 2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx) is expected to be mostly C++11 feature-complete, language-wise, but I'm not sure if the standard library implementation will be as well.

While C++11 was being standardised, there was a point where this function was specified to return `bool`. It was at this point that Microsoft added it to their implementation, and as C++11 was not supported anyway, it was simply not updated when the standard got updated.

The comments point out that this particular function was changed in VS2013 already, but still, if you want a C++11 implementation, then neither VS2012 nor VS2013 will do.

Comment: Yes, I know, that C++ 11 support is not fully implemented in VC11/12. I have checked features support for all compilers I decided to target. However, I'm quite disappointed. There were 4 (if I remember correctly) updates for VS2012, so fix should be already there. Unless MS does not update their `std` implementation after release...

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek Such library changes would break existing code that did work prior to the VS update. VS updates are not expected to break existing code. This doesn't mean that the standard library never receives updates with minor VS updates. It's the same with plenty of other compilers. You wouldn't see such an update from GCC 4.x.y to 4.x.(y+1) either, but you might see such an update from GCC 4.x.y to 4.(x+1).0.

Comment: In general, don't expect anything other than the most minor bugfixes to VC++ in post-release updates. They extremely conservative in that regard.